# Child_added get last item added javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

For my Firebase cloud functions, i'am trying to get the last child item added, in the aim to proceed a task for this item.
My structure is like this:

```
  -Tips
      -TipsId
             -Safe
                  -SafeId
                  -SafeId
                   etc
```

My goal is to get the last child SafeId item added.
i found this snippet, but the problem is that it is also trigger when item SafeId is remove.

```
ref.orderByChild('timestamp').startAt(Date.now()).on('child_added',function(snapshot) {
  console.log('new record', snapshot.val());
});
```

Answer (score 3):

To get just the last item, just `limitToLast()`:

```
ref.orderByChild('timestamp').limitToLast(1).on('child_added',function(snapshot) {
  console.log('new record', snapshot.val());
});
```

If you don't have a `timestamp` property, but have used `push()` to add the items, you can also use `orderByKey()`:

```
ref.orderByKey().limitToLast(1).on('child_added',function(snapshot) {
  console.log('new record', snapshot.val());
});
```