# How to update latest entry from Firebase-Database tree?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, real-time

I'd like to update (or synchronize) the latest entry from a tree in my Firebase-Database.

The structure looks like this:

[image]

I want to observe the latest entry only, without fetching all entries as 'EventTypeChildAdded' does.
However, I really want to observe the latest entry, so I'd like to call a function whenever there is a new 'latest' entry, so when a child gets added.

I already found this piece of code.

```
(DatabaseRef).queryOrderedByKey().queryLimitedToLast(1).observeSingleEventOfType
```

But this does not seem to observe the latest entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are on the wrong way. childadded does exactly what you need. Check the doc again.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#child-added

For the first time childadded fetches all the list but then only the item just added to the list.

> **Child Added**
>
> The child_added event is typically used when retrieving a list of
>   items from the database. Unlike value which returns the entire
>   contents of the location, child_added is triggered once for each
>   existing child and then again every time a new child is added to the
>   specified path. The event callback is passed a snapshot containing the
>   new child's data. For ordering purposes, it is also passed a second
>   argument containing the key of the previous child.

**EDIT:** 
To limit the childadded query to the last item:

```
ref.queryLimited(toLast: 1).observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
// parse snapshot to get the last item
```

Comment: Yes, I know that, that's why I'm asking this question. How can I get the latest element only (and update it), without getting all the data once? @uguboz

Comment: So why dont you put your trigger fucntion inside childadded? i didn't get what u re asking

Comment: Because childAdded will also fetch all data once. I don't want that. I want to get the latest entry only. `...child_added is triggered once for each existing child...`

Comment: can't you handle initial case with a flag maybe? Then it will work as u expected

Comment: It will work, I just didn't want to fetch all entries because there might be quite a lot. Anyways, I think I have to use childAdded. Thanks

Comment: aha ok i get it now. then u should try ref.queryLimited(toLast: 1).observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) ... instead of observing single event

Comment: for javascript equivalent of this question refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/46448886/5923606

Comment: Yeah, you're awesome, thanks a lot. If you could add this to your answer, I'd mark it as solved.

Comment: For IOS? how will be find out?